# D3.js about update the chart data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm stuck at a function call to update the data in a chart. The `add()` function was invoked, but it will only change the data correctly the first time. Here comes the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}

</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

d3.select("body").append("button").text("Randomize")
    .attr("onclick","add()");

d3.select("body").append("button").text("Pie").attr("onclick","drawpie()");

function drawpie(){
    var w = 300;
            var h = 300;

            var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];

            var outerRadius = w / 2;
            var innerRadius = 70;
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                            .outerRadius(outerRadius);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie();

            //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
            var color = d3.scale.category10();

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Set up groups
            var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                          .data(pie(data))
                          .enter()
                          .append("g")
                          .attr("class", "arc")
                          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

            //Draw arc paths
            arcs.append("path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })
                .attr("d", arc);

            //Labels
            arcs.append("text")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.value;
                });
}


function add(){
    console.log("call");

    d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div").each(function(d) {
        console.log("each");
            d3.select(this)
                .style("width", function(d) { return 50 + x(d) + "px"; })
                .text(function(d){return +(+d + 1)});
                /*.transition()
                .delay(1000)
                .duration(2000);*/
        })      
}


</script>
```

Would you please tell me how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that most of the problem are the function calls being wrong. I basically fixed that and simplified your add function...not sure if that is what you are looking for, but it should get you going...here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NY582/).

```
d3.select("body")
    .append("button")
    .text("Randomize")
    .on("click",add);

d3.select("body")
    .append("button")
    .text("Pie")
    .on("click",drawpie);
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NY582/1/) with a randomizing function for the data.

Comment: I has just visit the fiddle page and your code do little help but thanks as well.You can go to the fiddle page and click the randomize button for more than once,but it will only change the appearance of the chart the first time it was invoked.Thanks.

Comment: You need to keep changing the data being passed to the add function. So, add a parameter to the add function for passing the changing data. You will need to come up with the code to change the data.

Comment: I just added a randomizing function...see updated fiddle above in the edited response...but you will be using real data, of course. This is just for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for your patience:),I think I just got your point.In addition,I follow your advice to add a parameter just now, it works well,Thanks again for your demonstration.

Comment: No problem...communication takes iteration :) If this is what you needed then please mark the answer as accepted so others can benefit as well. Thanks.